# How to import table 180Mb without getting max_questions error

Tags: mysql, database, import, phpmyadmin

I have to import a 180Mb table on a shared (which means trouble I know) host and I'm getting the max_questions error. The limit is 75000 and they are not willing to higher the limit for even an hour. The number of queries as about 2000000.

I have been using bigdump to upload the gz file, but the limit is killing me.

Is there a way to split the table and upload it bit by bit or merge it somehow? I have been searching online, but solutions are mostly for people who can access the database settings.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that you have phpmyadmin installed in your website directory,
other wise download latest phpmyadmin version from official website.
and unzip it in your website directory
If that's the case then perform below steps.

Access your website directory via sftp or ftp.

If you can not access your website directory via sftp or ftp then you can setup cron jobs for fetching files.

Find the config.inc.php file located in the phpmyadmin directory. In my case it is located here:

**\public_html\phpmyadmin3.2.0.1\config.inc.php**

Find the line with $cfg[‘UploadDir’] on it and update it to:

**$cfg['UploadDir'] = 'upload';**

Create a directory called ‘upload’ within the phpmyadmin directory.

**\public_html\phpmyadmin3.2.0.1\upload**

Then place the large sql file that you are trying to import into the new upload directory.

Now when you go onto the db import page within phpmyadmin console 
you will notice a drop down present that wasn’t there before

it contains all of the sql files in the upload directory that you have just created.

You can now select this and begin the import.

Reference : http://daipratt.co.uk/importing-large-files-into-mysql-with-phpmyadmin/comment-page-4/

Comment: Thanks for the solution. Two questions. phpmyadmin is installed on a shared server and I cannot access it via ftp. I don't think I can add phpmyadmin to my website directory and access the database the table should be going in.
Are you sure this way I won't get the max_questions error?

Comment: You can try this,  https://code.google.com/p/code-discuz-tukyonline/downloads/detail?name=SQLDumpSplitter.zip&can=2&q=

Comment: Although I have tried bigdump and the program you're referring to is from 1999 I will give it a try.

Comment: No, also didn't work. No solution for it yet I guess.